# Node server to intercept all request from angular (http) to java spring backend

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, express

I am using express on node for routing and using angular as front end framework. I am using Redis for session. What i want to do is when ever i make http request from angular it should first go to node where i want to add additional headers information like auth token and all than pass it to java(spring) backend.

I want to do this because if i directly pass info from angular http it will be visible in network tab which might be security vulnerability.

So how can i make node interceptor between angular and java back end using node js server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http proxy middleware (https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) for similar purpose. Add it to your express application.

The middleware allows you to subscribe for proxy events and add/remove/modify headers that will go to you spring backend.

If I guess your needs correctly, you also might want to look at http://passportjs.org/ for authenticaion management.